# SOLR Special Characters and Emoticons

Tags: solr, lucene, hbase, codepages, indexer

I want to Index text data that contains Special characters like (currency symbols) and emoticons. Presently I am using following code to index this data: 
    `<fieldTypename="text"class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
    <tokenizerclass="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filterclass="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filterclass="solr.KeywordRepeatFilterFactory"/>
    <filterclass="solr.StopFilterFactory"words="stopwords.txt"
    ignoreCase="true"/>
    </analyzer>`

But while retrieving the data I can see that all the special characters and emoticons and spoiled e.g. 
Debtof��1,590.79settledfor��436.00
Please suggest what can be done here.

Application Flow: Data is first stored in HBASE and with real-time indexers it's updated to SOLR.

CDH Ver:5.4.5
SOLR Ver:4.10.3
HBASE VEer:1.0.0

Comment: I'm guessing this is UTF-16? Solr needs UTF-8. You'll probably have to convert to UTF-8 in your app. I don't know what language you're using, but Java's CharsetEncoder might be useful to you.

Comment: Tried changing Java code encoding to UTF-8 by using java -DFileEncoding property. Also these symbols come under UTF-8 when I checked UTF-8 char list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by converting smileys to HTMLHex and then storing it to SOLR. In SOLR now I can see that Hex code intact and which can be converted back to smileys.
Library Used:
[Lib to convert emoticons to Hex emoji-java](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java)